# Why the screen lock password no longer matches after using a different disk as /data

Tags: security, lock-screens, mount, password, data

I'm using a rooted Android 13 device, and an external SD-card that I mount as `/data` by editing the `fstab`. The SD-card is partitioned into few EXT4 partitions, and I can boot with any of them mounted as `/data` just by editing the `fstab`. For example, my current `fstab` entry is:

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data ext4 noatime,nosuid,nodev,discard wait,noflush_merge,fsync_mode=nobarrier,reserve_root=134217,resgid=1065,check,formattable,quota,reservedsize=128m,latemount,resize,checkpoint=fs
```

And I can change it to `mmcblk0p3`, to boot with a different partition as `/data`.

But there is an issue. Each time I boot with a different partition as `/data`, it works, BUT when I return to my previous one (same way, by editing `fstab`), it's lock screen password/PIN/Pattern **no longer matches**. It says like `Wrong PIN`.

Since I don't use encryption, I easily solve it by deleting the `locksettings.db` file from `/data/system`. But if I used encryption, it definitely wouldn't work.

My question is **why it happens**?

**Why, when I successfully unlock a phone booted with different `/data`, and then switch back to previous `/data`, the password that was set there no longer matches, and I have to delete it?**

**EDIT**: I made an experiment with a clean, not modded phone (without any SD cards or Root), that uses encryption and everything is stock. I took a full backup of the NAND flash, which includes GPT table, all partitions, and therefore the encrypted `userdata` too. After taking that full backup, I performed a Factory Reset on this phone, and booted up. Then, I turned phone off again, and flashed my full NAND backup. **The phone booted successfully, but yes, the password that was set there didnt match.**

This result is very weird. What could even get modified on the phone, if not something on the NAND flash?

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149650/discussion-on-question-by-melonfsck-why-the-screen-lock-password-no-longer-match); please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat].